# Use a avro complex types like array on Impala cloudera

Tags: hive, cloudera, avro, impala

I have created a hive table that contains a complex types ( array, struct)  with a Avro storage. I want to launch a Impala queries for retrieving  a data stored into array or struct.

Thanks

Comment: Great. Do you have a question? Like, _"does Impala support complex types even though the documentation says it does not?"_

Comment: Yes, Impala dont support a Avro complex types, I continue to  search a solution of this problem,